# Extern array of pointers to function

Tags: c, arrays, typedef, extern

A little bit of context first. My program features a header, `work.h`. This header contains a structure, some function definitions, and an extern array of pointers to my base functions.

**work.h**

```
typedef struct _foo {
  int id;
  char something[20];
} foo;

typedef void (*pointer_function)(foo *);

void do_first_to_foo(foo *);

void do_second_to_foo(foo *);

void do_third_to_foo(foo *);

extern pointer_function base_functions[3];
```

Then a program called `work.c` with the bodies of the functions, and then the main program `main.c`. Observe in the header `work.h` that I have defined prototypes of three functions, and the size of the array is 3, so the pointers on the extern array will point to each one of the 3 functions.

My questions are, how I can associate the pointers of the extern array with the three functions, and second, in which file I need to do it (`work.c` or `main.c`).

I understand this association I need to do it in the file `work.c`, but nothing else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `work.c`:

```
#include "work.h"

pointer_function base_functions[] = {
    do_first_to_foo,
    do_second_to_foo,
    do_third_to_foo };
```

Explanation: that array name is a global symbol, and needs to be actually defined in just one compilation unit (`.o` file produced from `.c` file). If you do not have it, linker will not find it. If you have multiple copies, linker will complain. You need just one, same as with global exported functions (which are not marked inline).

Edit: Added  showing `#include "work.h"`, which is important because it allows *compiler* to check that `extern` declaration matches the actual definition. If you leave it out, everything will compile and link without complaints, but you get no indication if there's a mismatch, which could wreak havoc like corrupt other data in memory when variable is used in other compilation units.

Comment: Beat me by *this* much ><.

Comment: One more thing I need to ask. If I have to call some of the functions in the pointer array in `main.c` , how I need to do it?

Comment: @CristianC. Just stick () after pointer expression, so with array of function pointers: arr[ind](param);